# How to access the columns after pivot_table operation (multiIndex dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multi-index

I initially had this dataframe:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({'slide': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0],
                           'time': [1673, 17892, 1132, 61730, 2323, 8491, 3958, 3432],
                           'frame': ['-1', '0', '-1', '0', '-1', '0', '-1', '0'],
                           'id': [1111, 1111, 1132, 1132, 4636, 4636, 7711, 7711],
                           'name': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'zoo', 'zoo', 'baz', 'baz']})
        df
           slide   time frame    id name
        0      0   1673    -1  1111  foo
        1      0  17892     0  1111  foo
        2      1   1132    -1  1132  bar
        3      1  61730     0  1132  bar
        4      2   2323    -1  4636  zoo
        5      2   8491     0  4636  zoo
        6      0   3958    -1  7711  baz
        7      0   3432     0  7711  baz
```

I did pivot_table to get the following:

```py
    pd.pivot_table(df,index = ['id','name'], values = 'time',columns = ['frame']).astype(int)

    df
    frame        -1      0
    id   name             
    1111 foo   1673  17892
    1132 bar   1132  61730
    4636 zoo   2323   8491
    7711 baz   3958   3432
```

I want to make the resulting dataframe as the following way (see below) but I don't know how to go about this.  I am new to pandas and just found out that multiindexing exist.. I tried accessing the columns with `df['0']['id']` and also with `df['0','id']` but both would throw me errors..... Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

```py
    df
    id   name    ON    OFF    
    1111 foo   1673  17892
    1132 bar   1132  61730
    4636 zoo   2323   8491
    7711 baz   3958   3432
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output `df = df.reset_index().set_index('id', drop = True).rename(columns = {'-1': 'ON', '0': 'OFF'})`

For reference, if you want to access a multiindex, you have to use tuples and `df.loc`. You can use `print(df.index)` to see how the indices are written. For example, `df.loc[(1111, 'foo'), '-1']` gets the value with id: 1111, name: foo at column '-1'.